# Google Chrome stops updating videochat when not on front

Tags: google-chrome, obs-studio

I have been capturing web based videochats (Jitsi and Whereby) using Open Bradcast Studio (OBS). Until recently I have been able to capture the video even when the browser windows is not on front provided that I no minimize it. But after a recent Chrome update the video turns black (i.e.: it is not updated) when another window in maximized over the browser. Browsing the web I have reached to somebody that has my same problem: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/windows-capture-turning-black-when-switching-screens.131971

I would like to knwo if there is any way to prevent this "feature". I want the video to keep being updated even when Chrome is not maximized on front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the address bar, type: `chrome://flags`
2. Search for "Throttle Javascript timers in background". Disable it.
3. Search for "Calculate window occlusion on Windows". Disable it.
4. Restart Chrome for the change to take effect.