# Microsoft Edge keeps displaying empty pages or even less

Tags: chromium, microsoft-edge

I have several computers where I work and all my Microsoft Edge instances are spearated (no account to sync the settings).

I have only one extension installed (uBlock Origin) on each machine but removing it unfortunately won't help.

I usually play Youtube videos or open Google Drive in my Edge, mostly in InPrivate mode.

*When I lock my computer or change to a different computer via Remote Desktop and change back to the running Edge*, I get this "layout":

[image]

As you can guess, it should show my Google Drive page. But it is *very empty*. There is no context menu, no click, not even a resize helps,  only a full reload will redraw the surface.

How can a hardware rendered video like Youtube be **not rendered AT ALL**? What did they modify in the Chromium source code?

So, anyone has any idea how to keep Edge displaying pages?

Comment: Maybe it is the same issue as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609324/google-chrome-stops-updating-videochat-when-not-on-front/1609354#1609354)

Comment: I will definitely try those settings, thanks for sharing.